# Simplifying an Integral over Two DiracDeltas

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
 Integrate[DiracDelta[a + k] DiracDelta[-b + k], {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
 (*DiracDelta[a + b]*)
```

This works fine.

But

```
 Integrate[k DiracDelta[a + k] DiracDelta[-b + k], {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

does not give the expected `b DiracDelta[a + b]`.

Why not? How can it be fixed?

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi The two answers are completely equivalent.

Comment: Looking at the possible issues in the `DiracDelta` documentation, there doesn't seem to be a definitive reason for this behavior. But at least a further integration will work correctly: `Assuming[a\[Element]Reals,Integrate[k DiracDelta[a+k] DiracDelta[-b+k],{k,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]},{b,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]]` yields `-a`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/12000/134) and you can use the workaround :

```
Integrate[k f[a + k] DiracDelta[-b + k], {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]},      
    Assumptions -> {{a, b} \[Element] Reals}] /. f -> DiracDelta

(* b DiracDelta[a + b] *)
```