# Convolution of two dirac delta functions

Tags: convolution

Why mathematica doesnt produce any answer to the following integral?

```
Integrate[0.040608386793220284*DiracDelta[w]*DiracDelta[-w + x], {w, -2, 2}]
```

and how can I get a solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look at [12000](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/12000/134)

Comment: @b.gatessucks than you very much

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using it incorrectly. The integral of a delta function is 1 when taken over all values:

```
Integrate[0.0406*DiracDelta[w]*DiracDelta[-w + x], {w, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

gives the expected

```
0.0406 DiracDelta[x]
```

Comment: but I am interested in the integral only in this range, not from minus infty to plus infty.

Comment: then specify x.. it can't know the value unless it knows x. Observe that `Integrate[0.0406*DiracDelta[w]*DiracDelta[-w + 100], {w, -2, 2}]` gives 0.

Comment: Integrate[f[x - w] DiracDelta[w], {w, -2, 2},
  Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals && x \[Element] Reals] /.
 f -> DiracDelta